# Finding a quotient field of the following set.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Consider the integral domain $D = \Bbb Z$. Let $S = \{1,p,p^2,p^3,\ldots \}$ with $p=2$ be a closed multiplicative set.
Find the quotient of field of $Q_S$ that formed.
For instance, if $D = \Bbb Z[i] = \{a+bi \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z \}$, then $Q_D = \{p+qi \mid p,q \in \Bbb Q \}$.

Any idea to start?

Comment: What do you mean with the quotient of field of $Q_S$ ? For an integral domain localization at a multiplicative set means adding the inverse of the elements in this set. Field of fraction means adding the inverse of every (non-zero) element.

Comment: For instance, if $D = \Bbb Z[i] = \{a+bi \mid a,b \in \Bbb Z \}$, then $Q_D = \{p+qi \mid p,q \in \Bbb Q \}$.

Comment: Do you see how to describe $S^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ ? It is a subring of $Frac(\Bbb{Z})=\Bbb{Q}$

Comment: Idk, how to describe it? What is $S^{-1} \Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: The localization of $\Bbb{Z}$ at $S$, which is obviously what your exercice is about. The field of fraction is the localization at $\Bbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

Comment: And then? What's next? $Q_S = \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ ?

Comment: $Q_S$ is your notation for $S^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ (adding to $\Bbb{Z}$ the inverses of elements of $S$)

Comment: Okay, and now, $Q_S = \Bbb Q$ ?

Comment: Since $Q_S$ is subring of $\Bbb Q$.